# Import astropy calling Python from PHP

Tags: php, python, astropy

I'd like to run a Python script from PHP (LAMP). The script imports astropy, and for some reason I am not able to successfully do that. I can reproduce the basic problem with the example files copied below. I don't think it is a permission or Python path problem. I can import numpy, scipy, etc., for example. I can also create a Python script to read and write files on that same directory (/www/var). I have the standard Python on /usr/bin/python and also the Anaconda version. Both have astropy and I get the same problem regardless of which one I use.

I suspect it is something about running the code as myself (which works fine) or as www-data (from the web browser). However, when I do this from the Linux terminal: sudo -u www-data php test.php, the code works as expected.

This is test.php:

```
<?php

echo "<p>begin test.php</p>";
system("python test.py");
echo "<p>end test.php</p>";

?>
```

And test.py:

```
print("this is test.py ...")

import sys, numpy, scipy, matplotlib
print("passed the import sys, numpy, scipy, matplotlib ...")

import astropy
print("passed the import astropy ...")
```

What I get when I open test.php is this:

```
begin test.php
this is test.py ... passed the import sys, numpy, scipy, matplotlib ... ERROR: TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found [genericpath]

end test.php
```

Answer (score 1):

What version of Astropy are you running?  Incidentally I'm pretty sure this is a known and fixed issue: https://github.com/astropy/astropy/pull/952

Also, current versions of Astropy require you to specify a configuration directory that the library can write to.  It doesn't necessarily know that /var/www is the correct "home" directory to use for the webserver, so you need to set the environment variable `XDG_CONFIG_HOME=/var/www` (make sure the `/var/www/astropy` directory exists too).

I think there are plans to simply this so that the library is at least importable without this additional setup.

Comment: I am using version 0.2.3 of astropy. I added this line to my php file:
putenv("XDG_CONFIG_HOME=/var/www/astropy");
and checked that it worked on my py code:
print(os.environ['XDG_CONFIG_HOME'])
It seems allright, but still get the same result.

Comment: Did you create the `/var/www/astropy` directory manually first and give the www-data user premission to write to it?  This thread on the astropy-dev mailing list might help: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/astropy-dev/y0MhEG6Uwic/fu75XJerV_gJ

Comment: Yes I created the directory and gave access to www-data. My mistake was to define XDG_CONFIG_HOME as /var/www/astropy. The correct way is to define it as /var/www. The link provided in the previous reply clarified this for me. Problem solved! Thank you Iguananaut.

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake then to have you set it to `/var/www/astropy` I'll fix that in the answer.

Comment: I updated my answer btw--if this worked for you could you please accept the answer? Thanks.